# Why is my iPad app not detecting orientation change?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, orientation

Using the following code gives me nothing... My view rotates. Can't understand it...

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}


- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    NSLog(@"I am starting to rotate");
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: Are you nesting view controllers?

Comment: Turns out my view controller was in a container...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be due to the way your VC is nested inside a heirarchy of VC's.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428936/how-to-handle-rotation-for-a-uiviewcontroller-that-isnt-on-top-of-uinavigationco) SO post should help you out:

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    if(self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
       self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
           NSLog(@"I am starting to rotate in Landscape");

    } else {
           NSLog(@"I am starting to rotate in Portrait");

    }
}
```

and leave this like how it was

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```